# Using modulus operator to keep within indices of container

Tags: c++, math, modulo

Assume I have a vector v with m elements in it, and a random access index to the vector called i.

When I increment the index, if it goes out of bounds, I want to index the first (zeroth) element. Similarly, when I decrement the index, if the index is < 0, I want to index to last element. At the moment I'm only moving through the container one element at a time, so came up with this function:

```
unsigned int GetIndexModM(int index,unsigned int m) {return (index + m) % m;}
```

The call-site might look like this:

```
std::vector<Whatever> v = ... // initialise with 5 elements
unsigned int i = 0;
unsigned int j = GetIndexModM(static_cast<int>(i) - 1,v.size()); // get preceeding index
```

This function will fail however if one subtracts a value > m from index:

```
unsigned int j = GetIndexModM(static_cast<int>(i) - 17,v.size()); // oops: returns -2
```

My question: What's the most elegant implementation of a function that takes any integer and returns it's place as an index?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The trick for handling MOD is this, which works with positive as well as negative numbers:

```
  val = ((val % mod_val) + mod_val) % mod_val;
```

For example, assume we want to keep value between 0 and 359 inclusive. We could use this:

```
  val = ((val % 360) + 360) % 360;
```

Here's a simple example in C++.

```
int getmod(int val, int mod) {
  return ((val % mod) + mod) % mod; 
}

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", getmod(50,360));   // prints 50
  printf("%d\n", getmod(-400,360)); // prints 320
  printf("%d\n", getmod(350,360));  // prints 350
  printf("%d\n", getmod(375,360));  // prints 15
  printf("%d\n", getmod(-725,360));  // prints 355


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: On some platforms, it might be faster to avoid the second modulo operation, at the cost of a comparison: `val = val % mod; return val < 0 ? val + mod : val;`

Comment: Does this work when `val < -mod_val`, or does it only handle negative integers with `-mod_val < val < 0`?  The modulus handles this correctly on the positive side.

Comment: @Andre Caron - It works in that scenario, I added another example (see last printf).

Comment: @dcp: Ah, I see!  You add *after* the first modulus.  Nice.

Comment: I have before just added a multiple of 'mod_val' large enough to ensure the mod is performed in positive space, eg. (val+3600)%360 works until val < -3600. This could be quicker than 2 mods if the modval is fixed or is shiftable to the size required.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, C++ doesn’t implement a proper modulus that still works correctly for negative integers.

I think the cleanest solution is indeed using `if` to take care of all cases properly. This at least makes the code obvious (because every case is **explicit**) and errors easier to find:

```
unsigned GetIndexModM(int index, unsigned m) {
    if (index < 0)
        return GetIndexModM(index + m, m);
    if (index >= m)
        return index % m;
    return index;
}
```

Comment: That's very inefficent if `index` is large and negative.

Comment: I tried your function with arguments -400,360 and I got 216 returned, but the answer should be 320.

Comment: @Mike That’s right – if this is a common use-case the function needs to be rewritten. On the other hand, for negative numbers close to zero this could actually be *faster* than the modulus method.

Answer (score -2):

The following ensures that `index` is in [0,`n`) but with only one modulus operation and no branches:

```
index = index % n + (index < 0)*n
```

where the first term (containing the modulus operator) gets the value into (`-n`,`n`) and the second term ensures that the value is in [0,`n`).

Note that this is unreliable when `n` is an unsigned type and in older (pre-11) versions of C++ where the % operator is implementation dependent for negative arguments.